# VLOOKUP error when looking up date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have been trying to use the CONCATENATE function in the Excel for creating multiple values of the financial statements for different years. My main formula is as shown:

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(CONCATENATE(A1,"-",C6,"-",RIGHT(B7,2)),"dd-mm-yy"),range,column,FALSE)
```

Although the `(TEXT(CONCATENATE(A1,"-",C6,"-",RIGHT(B7,2)),"dd-mm-yy")` gives me the date that I want (e.g. 10-Jun-10), when I use this in the `VLOOKUP` it does not treat it as a date and returns an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: I have also tried to put the DATEVALUE and VALUE function into it yet the VLOOKUP still won't give the desired result and will provide the outcome as #NA.

Comment: Try Date(year,month,date) for example: **=vlookup(date(right(b7,2),c6,a1),range,column,false)**

Comment: @Sam Post that as an answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the date so Excel and Vlookup can understand it as Date, Try the function **Date(year,month,date)** for example:
**=Vlookup(Date(right(B7,2),C6,A1),Range,Column,False)**